# Is this sign of hacked VPN?

Tags: privacy, vpn

[image: strange server in bar address]

I have some issues with Epicbrowser´s VPN.

I write a URL in the address bar like `duckduckgo.com`. Then `mfr.cdn.dcop.cz` appears just for a moment. It´s so brief that it took me a few days to capture the URL. Then the name of the URL I typed reappears like nothing ever happened.

What is this server? I was unable to find any information about it. Not even trace it.

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Welcome to the community. It might that you've become a victim of man in the middle, as in someone is snooping on you for every request it seems. Some other issues/nitpicks - why don't you just use a more trusted VPN and why do you keep on using a end of life OS?

Comment: Have you asked Epicbrowser's customer support?

Comment: Furthermore Windows 7 is end of life. You should not use it.

Comment: I recently changed PC and there is Windows10 Pro installed. Any proposals for safer VPN? Is there a way to find anything about the mfr.cdn.docp.cz ?